# sharing not working on unity android

Tags: android

I am having a problem in the regular sharing code of unity , its only working in messenger , but failing in instagram/twitter/facebook as below Facebook : Nothing is appearing , no text nor image. Twitter : Only text appearing , no image. Whatsapp : Sharing failed / try again. Instagram : Unfortunately , instagram has stopped. Snapchat : The app opens without anything .

This is my code.

```
if (rayCast.collider != null && rayCast.transform.gameObject.tag == "share")
             {
                 Debug.Log ("Capture SCreen");
                 Application.CaptureScreenshot ("Bla.png");
                 Debug.Log ("screen captured");
                 ShareImage (Application.persistentDataPath + "/sceenshot.png", "How many balloons you can tap in Yellow Hunter! ", "xx", "xx");
                 Debug.Log ("Sharing done");
             }

 public static void ShareImage(string imageFileName, string subject, string title, string message)
 {
```

#if UNITY_ANDROID

```
     AndroidJavaClass intentClass = new AndroidJavaClass("android.content.Intent");
     AndroidJavaObject intentObject = new AndroidJavaObject("android.content.Intent");

     intentObject.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("setAction", intentClass.GetStatic<string>("ACTION_SEND"));
     intentObject.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("setType", "image/*");
     intentObject.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("putExtra", intentClass.GetStatic<string>("EXTRA_SUBJECT"), subject);
     intentObject.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("putExtra", intentClass.GetStatic<string>("EXTRA_TITLE"), title);
     intentObject.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("putExtra", intentClass.GetStatic<string>("EXTRA_TEXT"), message);

     AndroidJavaClass uriClass = new AndroidJavaClass("android.net.Uri");
     AndroidJavaObject fileObject = new AndroidJavaObject("java.io.File", imageFileName);
     AndroidJavaObject uriObject = uriClass.CallStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("fromFile", fileObject);

     bool fileExist = fileObject.Call<bool>("exists");
     Debug.Log("File exist : " + fileExist);
     // Attach image to intent
     if (fileExist)
         intentObject.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("putExtra", intentClass.GetStatic<string>("EXTRA_STREAM"), uriObject);
     AndroidJavaClass unity = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer");
     AndroidJavaObject currentActivity = unity.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");
     currentActivity.Call("startActivity", intentObject);
```

#endif

Comment: Is it an issue that you are saving a screenshot to `"Bla.png"` and then trying to share the `"/sceenshot.png"`?  (also note the typo in `screenshot`)

Comment: thanks alot , that was the issue :))